# How can I start manipulating an scRNA seq .txt matrix in R?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, rna-seq, seurat

I'm really new to this, so please forgive my general lack of understanding.

I've been trying to take the dataset that is provided [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE141445) (I download the .txt file at the bottom). It's scRNA-seq data and I'm trying to use seurat to process it and make some graphs. However, every time I try loading it, it doesn't work and it says I need a arcode file. How can I convert this file into something that'll run through seurat and make a barcode file? I really appreciate anyone's help in this. Thank you!

Comment: Need to include a code block that show how this ".txt" file which was actually a tarred.gz file) was expanded and read into an R object and then handed to "seurat" (which a think is actually spelled "Seurat". Be sure to include things like code to install and load the package before the code that was used to "process".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Reading it is trivial, use standard functions such as:

```
d <- data.table::fread("GSM4203181_data.raw.matrix.txt")
```

The "barcodes" are the colnames, the "features" are the first column, so the genes.

```
> d[1:5,1:5]
              V1 AAACCTGAGAGATGAG-1 AAACCTGCACCAGGCT-1 AAACCTGGTTAAGACA-1
1:  RP11-34P13.7                  0                  0                  0
2:  RP11-34P13.8                  0                  0                  0
3:    FO538757.2                  1                  0                  0
4:    AP006222.2                  2                  1                  0
5: RP4-669L17.10                  0                  0                  0
   AAACCTGGTTGAGTTC-1
1:                  0
2:                  0
3:                  0
4:                  0
5:                  0
```

From here you can construct your Seurat object manually, e.g. via https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Seurat/versions/3.0.1/topics/CreateSeuratObject

Comment: Thisis really useful, thank you! I followed your link and then went through with the tutorial from satijalab and trial-and-error'ed my way through to completion. Thank you so much!